# Google Tag Manager with Firebase

Tags: android, google-tag-manager

What does below LOG means, is it fine or its something that I have to be worried of because I am getting this on every app launch. Any help would be appreciated

```
W/GoogleTagManager: Ignoring container asset GTM-XXXXXX (does not match (gtm-[a-z0-9]{1,10})\.json)
   W/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded)
    I/GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager initilization took 206ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to add the asset to the containers folder without renaming it.

For example, if you container ID is GTM-ABC123, You would go to the versions tab in Google Tag Manager's web UI, select the actions dropdown, and select download. Your browser should prompt you to save the file with the suggested name of GTM-ABC123.json. Take that file and move it into your assets/containers folder.

Comment: Thanks. But I have already done that, its still showing that after adding the file.

Comment: What's the contents of your assets/containers path? Does that file case-insensitively match (gtm-[a-z0-9]{1,10})\.json

Comment: When I try to download, the browser download automatically without any extension as GTM-MZSYUI, and my log gives error as W/GoogleTagManager: Container GTM-MZSYUI loading failed. But when I change the extension of the file to .json it gives me error as  Saved resource not found: resource_GTM-MZSYUI
08-10 17:37:49.368 29963-30581/com.softdew.orahi I/GoogleTagManager: Resource data is corrupted, and when I use Export instead of Download from the dashboard and use it the it gives me Error when loading resource from url: Bad response: 403, PS: My container is already in published state.

Comment: Is that your actual containerid? When you go to admin/container settings, what is your container type? If it's legacy Android or legacy iOS, then you're trying to use the new SDK with an old container.

Comment: Yes, its my container ID, container type showing Legacy Android, what change I have to make please tell.

Comment: Ya it did helped, I have now created a new container for Firebase, now its not that serious but I am getting below log now :   GoogleTagManager: Tag Manager's event handler WILL NOT be installed (no container loaded), is this event temporary or its a blocker?

Comment: Have you added the container to the assets/containers path in your project?

Comment: All worked fine as suggested, I have even created a new container. But one problem I faced is sometime the container throw 403 and causes my application to crash. I cant even prevent it. I checked the container is there. This is happening sometime but whenever it happens its continous.

Comment: Do you have logs for this? If so can you post them here, or email them to my first initial last name AT google dot com